# Tags Selectively Stripped From Html Elements from Source

Tags: c#, asp.net, browser, html-rendering

We have an asp.net webform pulling markup from a database and sending to browser to render as html.

Html is being selectively stripped from html tags from only some of this markup and is instead displaying as plain text.

I have checked source and all of the tags are there so it's unlikely to be a server issue with the asp controller (I checked anyway, see below) - I have checked the validity of the html at validator.w3c.org and there is nothing the browser should be removing as invalid.

The controller on the webform is asp:literal so I thought it might have been in the wrong mode, however I have played around with this and there is no improvement. Also, some of the html was being rendered correctly anyway so this was always unlikely to be the issue.

I think it might have something to do with a network request overriding some styling as it initially renders correctly but as the page loads additional paints remove the tags from displayed page. Previews of the module in question in network tab also render correctly.

Ok, so the code in source is:

```
<div class='classname class'>
   <div class='classname'>
      <div class='classname'><img id = 'myImg' src='https://imgurl.com' alt='A Description'></div>
   </div>
   <div class='classname'>
      <h1>A Heading of My Subject</h1>
      <p class='classname'>And then some more.</p>
   </div>
   <div id='myId'>
      <div class='classname'>
         <h1> A Heading of My Subject </h1>
         <p>Stripping subject from text.</p>
         <h2> A Secondary Heading for More Info</h2>
         <p>An abstraction of my paragraph text.</p>
         <h2> Another Secondary Heading </h2>
         <p>Lorem Ipsum forever!</p>
         <p>And yet another paragraph.</p>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

The actual html rendered is:

```
<div class='classname class'>
   <div class='classname'>
      <div class='classname'><img id = 'myImg' src='https://imgurl.com' alt='A Description'></div>
   </div>
   <div class='classname'>
      <h1>A Heading of My Subject</h1>
      <p class='classname'>And then some more.</p>
   </div>
   <div id='myId'>
      <div class='classname'>
         " A Heading of My Subject 
         Stripping subject from text.
         A Secondary Heading for More Info
         An abstraction of my paragraph text.
         Another Secondary Heading 
         Lorem Ipsum forever!
         And yet another paragraph."
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

It is curious that the double quotes are being added also, not sure what is going on there.

The relevant code-behind is:

```
Page.Title = Name + " - " + Var;
LocOutput.Append("<div class='classname'>" + Environment.NewLine);
LocOutput.Append("<div class='classname'>" + Environment.NewLine);
LocOutput.Append("<div class='classname'><img id='asd' src='" + imgurl + "' alt='" + imgdescription + "'></div>" + Environment.NewLine);
LocOutput.Append("</div>" + Environment.NewLine);
LocOutput.Append("<div class ='classname'><h1>" + Name + "</h1><p class='classname'>" + Name2 + "</p></div>" + Environment.NewLine);
LocOutput.Append("<div id = 'idNameo'><div class ='classname'>" + Content + "</div></div>" + Environment.NewLine);

if (myVar == "condition")
{
    LocOutput.Append("<div id = 'idNameod2' value = '" + Var3+ "'></div>" + Environment.NewLine);
}
LocOutput.Append("</div>" + Environment.NewLine);
LocationDetails.Text = LocOutput.ToString();
```

The stripped away html is located entirely within the Content variable.

The control is :

```
<asp:Literal ID="LocationDetails" runat="server"/>
```

Comment: Have you looked at what is being downloaded to your browser using a tool like Fiddler. You say the browser is doing the stripping. But it could be some6on the server, or a proxy, or... Does it only happen with one browser? One version? What browser, what version?

Comment: Ok yes, you are correct, the browser being the cause is just my guess, I have edited answer to reflect this. 

I have reproduced on Chrome 75.0.3770.142 64 bit, Firefox 65.0 64-bit, and Edge  42.17134.1.0.

Comment: I have added code-behind - the controller is sending everything as a string. I have tried mode changing and this doesn't alter anything so I am hesitant to say it is the server. I will check on fiddle, haven't used before so might be very helpful...

Comment: @washboardalex use Replace on the string variables, replace double quotes, single quotes,  <, > tags with empty strings. see if this will fix it.

Comment: asp:literal is a `control` not a `controller`. watch out for this. controllers are important things in asp.net mvc so it's significant to point out.

Comment: Try prefacing your strings with `@`. If a keyword comes up in a string there could be a problem without `@`. Ex: `@"<div class='classname'>"`. Something is definitely going on in `Control` but we can't see where the string comes from.

Comment: The string was not the issue, neither the browser. Something is coming down the wire from another module on the page (we use DNN). I removed the offending module and the html renders correctly now. I am currently filtering network traffic via request blocking to isolate the cause, will update page with answer when I get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause in this case was some javascript stripping html as part of an insertion of data following an AJAX call:

```
var desc = $('#elemId').find('.more').text();
desc = desc.replace("(random data)", randomDataVar);
```

The method was accessing inner text but after the replacement was inserting it back into innerHTML.

I accessed innerHTML directly to solve this issue:

```
var desc = document.getElementsByClassName('more')[0];
desc.innerHTML = desc.innerHTML.replace("(random data)", randomDataVar);
```